# gulp error : Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-build-web'

Tags: angular, sharepoint

issue I am facing to create the share point web part. To create the web part following libraries should be installed :

```
call npm install -g chalk
call npm install -g loadash
call npm install -g tar-fs
call npm install -g update-notifier
call npm install -g yeoman-generator
call npm install -g yosay

call npm install -g yo
call npm install -g gulp

call npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
```

After installing above libraries web part created correctly. But after few days when I am creating new webpart again following error occurred:
gulp error :

> Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-build-web'

When I install this this library then another library missing error occurred.

When I again install above libraries then every these libraries then everything  works  fine.

So the issue is Should I need to install above libraries again when I create the web part?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following :-

```
npm -g install npm@next
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

then try your command again.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to create a webpart with Sharepoint Framework I got the same error message.

I have `gulp 3.9.1 version` and I solved uninstalling my version of `NodeJS` and installing the `10.13.0 version`.

Then I've done:

```
npm install --save-dev @microsoft/sp-build-web.
```

and everything worked for me :)